# Working with external JavaScript functions and HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Thank you in advance for helping me with my issue. I was wondering if someone could explain this for me as i am self teaching about JavaScript JQuery. What i am trying to do is push a message into a variable that is in the parameters of a function. Then i want to display the message using the function by calling it back to the html file that i originally had. So i want write a message in my function and print to my html page. I think i maybe in the right direction here is my source code. I am trying to get use to write with external javascript files as i think it is much cleaner way of working with HTML, CSS3, and JavaScript.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title></title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src=".js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
 </head>
 <body>

<form>


    <input type="button" value="Click me" id="message "onclick="test();" />

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

External JavaScript file.

```
 function test(message){


      alert("Hello");


 }
```

Comment: Is there a specific issue that you are having?  Also you script tag has no name in front of the .js in the src attribute.

Comment: Where do you want the message to be printed and when?

Comment: http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/javascript is a decent place to start.

Comment: What should `message` be? Or where should it come from?

Comment: Well it should display just on the screen when i click the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show message in popup do it this way

**Html:**

```
<input type="button" value="Show message in popup" id="message "onclick="test2('hii this is my message');" />
```

**JS:**

```
function test2(message)
{
 alert(message);   
}
```

To show message in div

**Html:**

```
 <input type="button" value="Show message in div" id="message "onclick="test('hii this is my message');" />
 <div id="message"> </div>
```

**JS**

```
function test(message)
{
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = message;
}
```

**Demo :** [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sid_m/ckxat50m/1/)

Comment: so does the getElementById get it from the HTML file?

Comment: Thank you everyone for their feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Use `this.value` to get the value of the input

```
<input type="button" value="Click me" id="message" onclick="test(this.value);" />
```

And then use the message you get

```
function test(message){

    alert(message);

}
```

To show this message on your page, create an element on the page

```
<div id="message"></div>
```

Then, in your `test` function, instead of `alert`, set the `innerText` or `innerHTML` to the message

```
document.getElementById('message').innerText = message;
```

Comment: This does work i just had my name wrong for the name of the external javascript file.

Comment: So does the getElementById get the id from the HTML and push it through to the function and then send the message back to the HTML?

Comment: Do i have to do this in a div tag for this to work? Because it is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

Adding the message: The easy way to do this would be by using jQuery or a javascript library of your choice. Otherwise, you can simply do this:

Create an empty div to display the msg with an `id="msg"`

and in your javascript function:

```
document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "Your message";
```

jQuery is much more fun: you can use readily available functions like `.html()` and `.append()`

Comment: What do i put in the function () in the html after i call the id

Comment: Do i pass anything through it?

Answer (score -3):

You definitely want to do this, as it is much MUCH cleaner to do so. It also lets you use the same code in multiple places.

Look at this: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_whereto.asp

(down by 'external JavaScript')

Essentially, you need to save the `.js` file as an actual file, like `filename.js`:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="filewithcode.js"></script>`

where `filewithcode.js` is the file path to the JavaScript file you have created.

Hope this helps

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: The question is rather vague, I thought it was a more conceptual 'how to/is this best practice' question

Comment: I apologize about my vaugeness but i am new to programming. Just getting all the concepts down and created a library for JavaScript, HTML5, CSS3, JQuery.

Comment: Yes this helped and i know how to call on external .js files but was unsure how to get the function to process my message to the HTML file